# VS2019 Preview 4: Add a Blazor Server App to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Source Control Adds it to Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to add my solution to my Team Foundation Server repository, but it's adding it to the Git repository instead.

To reproduce:

1. open VS2019 Preview 4
2. create a new Blazor Server Side App
3. go to Tools/Options/Source Control and set it to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
4. go to the newly created Solution, and add it to Source Control

It adds it to Git and not to Visual Studio Source Control, and changes the Tools/Options/Source Control to Git too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's time to move to git, no!?! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't check the "**Add to Source Control**" box when you initially create the project.

Instead of this, you could select Add to Source Control when you create projects. Try to connect to a TFS team project in Team Explorer before creating new projects. This should do the trick.

[image]

If you do not want to create another solution, you could also give a try with below way:

1. Tools -> Options -> Source Control tab -> Choose None in the plugin selection. (It may close the solution).
2. Again Tools -> Options -> Source Control tab -> Choose VS TFS in plugin selection
3. Go to the root folder of your project and **delete any .git files and folders** (It may be hidden - may need to show it first)
4. In visual studio connect to a TFS team project
5. Try adding the solution to source control -> this should display the TFS dialogue